# How do I reference my from from my Django view?

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, import, view

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have the following in my project hierarchy ...

```
+ project
    + web
        + views
            tax_calculator.py
        + forms
            __init__.py
            tax_calculator_form.py
```

The contents of tax_calculator_form.py are as follows ...

```
from django import forms
from localflavor.us.forms import USStateSelect


class TaxCalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    state = forms.CharField(widget=USStateSelect)
    net_income = forms.IntegerField()
    s_corp_salary = forms.IntegerField()
```

The **init**.py file is empty.  The views/tax_calculator.py file contains this line ...

```
from web.forms import TaxCalculatorForm
```

but I'm getting the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TaxCalculatorForm' from 'web.forms'
```

What's the proper way to include my form in my view file?

Comment: That should be `from web.forms.tax_calculator_form import TaxCalculatorForm` here. Often however all forms are defined in a `forms.py`, and views in `views.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
from .tax_calculator_form import TaxCalculatorForm
```

inside your forms/**init**.py